# Integrating Google Calendar in website Using IFrame with exact features

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

Is it possible to display Google calendar in a website using Iframe/other options, and it should have the Add/Edit/Delete events features in calendar in the website itself, should not go to google calendar.

Users will login using there gmail and password and the calendar gets displayed and the users can add/edit/delete events without going to google calendar.

Any help would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find a solution men ?

Answer (score -1):

following link may help you

[Embed Gcalender on website](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en)

and you can add iframe like this

```
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=mahajan.anil89%40gmail.com&ctz=Asia/Calcutta" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

and you can programmatically change src attribute according to user

Comment: This is a read-only calendar view.  OP asked for the ability to edit.